# User-defined function to VLOOKUP with dynamic path into closed workbook (without opening it)

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I'm a begginer in VBA and am trying to develop a funcion to VLOOKUP from a closed workbook dynamically changing the lookup table.

The reason I'm trying to do this using a function instead of directly using VLOOKUP in my spreadsheet is that I must dynamically change the workbook I'm opening according to the day of the month.

This is the code I've developed:

```
Public Function PROC_VAZOES(dia, bacia, indice_coluna)

Dim path As String
path = "'Y:\File Path\[Relatorio_previsao_diaria_" & Application.Text(dia, "DD") & "_" & Application.Text(dia, "MM") & "_2019_para_" & Application.Text(dia, "DD") & "_" & Application.Text(dia, "MM") & "_2019.xls]Diária_4'!$B$1:$I$173"

PROC_VAZOES = Application.VLookup(bacia, path, indice_coluna, False)

End Function
```

("dia" is a date with the format "DD/MM/YYYY")

But I'm getting as return the #VALUE error. I believe this is due to the fact that the path variable is still a string and its value has double quotes in its beggining and end.

Would anyone be able to help find a solution to this problem? I've tried to check the many other questions about VLOOKUPs with dynamic path but could find none that deals with my problem.

Comment: Calling `VLookup` on a closed workbook _in VBA_ does not work at all (but a Vlookup formula in a cell to a closed workbook _does_ work).

Comment: Would index/match work on a closed workbook if called in VBA?

Comment: Also No.  What does work is vba that writes a vlookup formula into a cell.  But _that_ doesn't work as a UDF. If the data in the close workbook is suitably structured you could consider a query